# RecyclerView infinite scroll in both directions

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement a `RecyclerView` that never finishes. Before the first item there is the last item and after the last item is scrolled, the first item is shown.
How can I do that?
What Im trying to achieve is a music player that shows the current song, the song before and after.
Like this:
[image]

(ps. is there a better way than using a `recyclerview`?)

Comment: Do you have try somethings. And can we see it (code) to more understand what you want.

Comment: @crammeur thank you for answering but I just realized how I can fix that! All I needed was to implement a doubly linked list and use it in recyclerview adapter! I forgot that I don't always have to use ArrayList class in adapter! I'm writing the custom list class, I'll post it when It's done :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way I have seen this done is to define the number of items that you have to display as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. In `onBindViewHolder()` of the adapter you will have something like:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (mItems == null) ? 0 : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

Now you can't really have `Integer.MAX_VALUE` items to display, so this is a small lie to the `RecyclerView`. In your code, map the index value from 0...Integer.MAX_VALUE-1 to 0...your_item_count-1 like this in `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
int realPos = position % mItems.size();
```

Use `realPos` instead of the position that the `RecyclerView` passes in.

All that is left is to scroll the `RecyclerView` to the middle of the range:

```
mRecycler.scrollToPosition(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2);
```

This works OK, but is it perfect? No, but close enough; I don't think anyone will scroll enough to see the flaw. (It will stop wrapping at the extremes.)

Comment: Yes I think It works! However its better to use `mRecycler.scrollToPosition((Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2)-(Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2)% mItems.size());` instead, to scroll to the first item. ps. does this way make performance issues? because of all the big numbers

Comment: @Apptic I just positioned randomly. As for performance issues, you aren't really keeping that large of an array and `RecyclerView` just maintains a small pool of view holders so, no, I don't think that there is a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented it in a simpler way with explanation, you or anyone for reference can check this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76364112/10058095